# If $AB=AC \implies B=C$, then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

So we want to prove the following statement (for matrices $A,B,C)$

> $A$ is invertible $\iff (AB=AC \implies B=C)$

To prove the $\Rightarrow$ side is not difficult, but I'm having trouble with  the $\Leftarrow $ side. This is my attempt at it:

$(AB=AC \Rightarrow B=C) \Leftrightarrow \exists X, Y$ such that $XAB=B$ and $YAC =C$.

$XAB = B \Leftrightarrow XAI = I \Rightarrow XA = I \Rightarrow XI = IA^{-1} \Rightarrow X=A^{-1}$

Similarly we find that $Y=A^{-1} = X$, so we have proved the $\Leftarrow$ side.

Is this proof correct? The first step especially is one where I have some doubt.

Comment: It is not explained what are these $X,Y$? Why should they exist?

Comment: The right-hand statement "$AB = AC \implies B = C$" has an implicit quantifier "For all $B$ and $C$". Proving the contrapositive would be a natural approach: If $A$ is not invertible, there exist $B$ and $C$ such that $AB = AC$ and $B \neq C$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang $A=0$ would do, right?

Comment: @YakSalTafri: Unfortunately not: You don't have control over $A$, only over $B$ and $C$ _once $A$ is chosen_.

Comment: @YakSalTafri that's just **one** example of non invertible matrix. You need prove it for **every** non invertible matrix.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Any hint as to how to prove that statement? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for linear maps
$$AC=AB\Rightarrow B=C$$
means that $A$ is injective. To see this consider any $B,C$ that differ only on their restriction to $\ker A$, then $AC=AB$, but $B\not=C$ unless $\ker A=0$.

Injective endomorphisms of vector spaces are isomorphisms, so $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Why is it an endomorphism? What about infinite dimensions? The question does not specify them being matrices, if that was the assumption.

Comment: @TheVee No you're right, without more info this argument doesn't work...

Comment: For what it's worth, there are two notions of injectivity in your answer: Injectivity of multiplication by $A$ _as a map on a space of matrices_ (or linear transformations), and injectivity of a linear transformation $A$ _as a map between vector spaces_. It's not tautological that these notions are the same.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang True, added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB=AC=D$

$ (AB=AC=D \implies B=C) \iff AX=D \ $ has only one solution.

$\iff A(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)\ \ $has only one solution.

$\iff Ax=d_1,Ax=d_2,...,Ax=d_n\ $ all has only one solution.

$\iff A\ $ is invertible